# What documents does a US citizen need to visit Mexico?

Tags: transit-visas, us-citizens, mexico

I am a U.S citizen. Do i need a passport and visa when flying from California to Guadalajara. I do not have a passport and I will only be visiting Guadalajara for 4 days on business.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  According to the Mexican Consulate General in San Francisco, as a US citizen [you need a passport to enter Mexico](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico):

> Effective March 1st 2010, all visitors traveling to Mexico either by air, land or sea are required to present a valid (non-expired) Passport or Travel Document from their country to enter Mexico.

To apply for a passport, you can start by visiting the US State Department's [How to Apply for a Passport](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/how-to-apply.html) page.